# webservice handling protobuf

Tags: java, spring, web-services, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to make a webservice work with protobuf and json.
The issue lies in the fact I want need to be able to read the inputStream in order to build my proto (at least I do not see another way of doing it).

I created a converter for protobuf :

```
public class ProtobufMessageConverter extends AbstractHttpMessageConverter<MyProto>{

    @Override
    protected boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) {
        return MyProto.class.equals(aClass);
    }

    @Override
    protected MyProto readInternal(Class<? extends MyProto> aClass, HttpInputMessage httpInputMessage)
            throws IOException, HttpMessageNotReadableException {
        return MyProto.parseFrom(httpInputMessage.getBody());
    }

    @Override
    protected void writeInternal(MyProto proto, HttpOutputMessage httpOutputMessage)
            throws IOException, HttpMessageNotWritableException {
        OutputStream wr = httpOutputMessage.getBody();
        wr.write(proto.toByteArray());
        wr.close();
    }
}
```

used in my springconfiguration :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.test")
public class SpringMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> httpMessageConverters) {
        httpMessageConverters.add(new ProtobufMessageConverter(new MediaType("application","octet-stream")));

        addDefaultHttpMessageConverters(httpMessageConverters);
    }
}
```

My controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/proto", method = {POST}, consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE})
@ResponseBody
public MyProto openProto(@RequestHeader(value = "Host") String host, @RequestBody
   MyProto strBody, HttpServletRequest httpRequest
) throws InterruptedException {
    return null;
}
```

The problem is that if I let the controller like this, I get an error because my webservice is not supporting the application/octet-stream.

[main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector - Started ServerConnector@73b05494{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8180}
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:155) ...

If I put String in the @RequestBody, then I go inside my method but it seems not to be using the converter and the string cannot be cast into MyProto with a parseFrom function.

Would you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer actually.
We need to consider the protobuf as a byte[]. There is already a HttpMessageConverter for this type. Hence the ResponseBody should be

```
public byte[] openProto(@RequestHeader(value = "Host") String host, @RequestBody
   byte[] strBody, HttpServletRequest httpRequest
) throws InterruptedException {
    return null;
}
```